# Direct Proof with Quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

How can i use direct proof to prove that the function $n^2+5n+6$ is even when $n$ is odd and even, for all natural numbers?

Comment: **Hint:** Start with the formal definition of "$x$ is even".

Comment: What does "when $n$ is odd and even" mean?

Comment: @Randal Yes, that is badly worded.  A charitable reading is that they intended "when $n$ is odd and when it is even", or "whether $n$ is odd or even"

Comment: $n^2+5n+6=(?)(?)$, a product of consecutive terms, so one factor must be even and hence the expression is even !

Comment: The question was just completely changed so that the answer is no longer correct.

Comment: To further what Steve has said, this question should not have been changed in this manner because it **completely** invalidates grxxytomy's answer, which is rather rude and disrespectful towards the work they put into it. @OrwellLegend, if you would like your "new question" answered, then ask it separately - preferably with the additions of context. But as for this current question, I am going to rollback the edit you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$. Now, 
$$\begin{align}
n^2 + 5n + 6 &= (2k)^2 + 5(2k) + 6\\
&= 4k^2 + 10k + 6 \\
&= 2(k^2 +5k + 3) \\
&= 2m, \text{ for some integer } m
\end{align}$$
where the last equality holds because the set of integers is closed under addition. That is, the sum of integers will always be an integer.

We can work it out similarly if $n$ is odd, i.e. $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$.

User Chinnapparaj R gives another approach to this problem in their comment. Hopefully you find these both of some use.